# cryptography , please help

Tags: cryptography

I have a cipher system with $n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3$ , where every $p_i$ is prime , and a message $M$ ciphered in the following way  $$E(M)=(M^{K_1})\mod n$$  I need to find the minimal number of unhidden messages in this system , and I have no clue where to even go.

thank very much for the help in advance

[Editor's note: from the comments an *unhidden message* is one where $E(M)=M$]

Comment: What is an unhidden message?

Comment: an unhidden message is where E(M)=M

Comment: You haven't told us what $K_1$ is either

Comment: k1 is a key , not defined in the general question , only needs to be legal in the way of exponential cipher

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the CRT implies that $E(M)=M$ iff $M^{K_1} \pmod{p_i} \equiv M$ for $i=1,2,3$.
So think about the prime situation first.